# How to call C++ functions/methods via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++

does anybody know how to call C++ functions or methods via JavaScript.
Need scripting like Lua/Python-C++ but with JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which platform, in what context?

Comment: Relevant search results for this question can be found [here](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+call+c%2B%2B+(code%7Cfunction)&oq=javascript+call+c%2B%2B+(code%7Cfunction)&gs_l=hp.12..0i8i30.21097.25849.1.27588.11.11.0.0.0.1.117.763.10j1.11.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.AmJP4Us_wqQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmQ&fp=d5bbde17dd6cca0a&biw=1366&bih=639)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try [Google's V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/):

> open source JavaScript engine.
>
> V8 is written in C++ and is used in Google Chrome, the open source browser from Google.
>
> V8 implements ECMAScript as specified in [ECMA-262](http://web.archive.org/web/20091005103232/http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), 3rd edition, and runs on Windows XP and Vista, Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard), and Linux systems that use IA-32 or ARM processors.
>
> V8 can run standalone, or can be [embedded](http://web.archive.org/web/20091005103232/http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html) into any C++ application...

Answer (score 7):

this is bit old question but if someone stumble upon this to find an answer i think this will be helpful https://developers.google.com/native-client/ but this works on Chrome only.

Comment: Native Client is no longer supported in Chrome, but it is still possible to call C++ functions from JavaScript using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any cross-browser solution, but for Firefox I'd suggest [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM).

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla's Spidermonkey:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_C_Engine_Embedder%27s_Guide

Comment: The question is how to access C++ objects from javascript...not how to access Javascript from within C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different JavaScript engines you could use. I don't think they have a common programming interface so you'd have to pick one and work with it. Google Chrome uses [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) and Mozilla uses [spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_C_Engine_Embedder%27s_Guide). Both V8 and spidermonkey are open source. I'd guess that spidermonkey is more mature since it's been around for a while. There is also [WebKit JavaScript engine](http://webkit.org/projects/javascript/index.html) from Apple, also open source.

Wikipedia also has [a list of JavaScript engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript instructions are interpreted by the browser, and I don't think there is a C++ layer for JS (not that it would make much sense anyway). 
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: He wants to use JavaScript as an extension language for his C++ application.

Comment: This is not really an answer, if so, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling a server-side script via a Javascript XHR, that executes your C-program on system level?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript have different realisation (in different browsers)
On Windows platform you can use C++ code in form of COM-objects